# Is the phrase "in that" interchangeable with "since"?

Tags: grammar

My boss likes to use "in that" when he really means "since." Is this acceptable? If not, what is the rule that I can tell him?

Comment: An example or two would help so we can understand in what case he's using "in that" where you believe he means "since".

Comment: When it comes to bosses, wait until they ask . . .

Comment: Please add examples. We can't tell you if your boss is wrong if we don't know what he's saying.

Answer (score 4):

*Since* can be used in either a causative or temporal sense, whereas *in that* can only be used in the more causative sense (*in that* has other senses, but we are mostly concerned with where it overlaps with *since*).

In the causative sense, it is acceptable to say either *I like X since it does Y* or *I like X in that it does Y.*  If you are unsure, try replacing *since/in that* with *because;* if the sentence still works, then you have the causative sense: e.g. *I like X because it does Y,* which still conveys the same meaning.

In the temporal sense, however, only *since* works.  Thus, *I have liked X since it did Y* means *I began to like X after it did Y.*  However, *I have liked X in that it did Y* means *I have liked X because it did Y.*

The lines are blurry and somewhat confusing.  The main thing to remember is that, historically speaking, *since* is temporal and *in that* is causative.  Since the days of yore their senses have been overlapping each other, however, and so I wouldn't be too surprised that the two are 'misused', so to speak.

Answer (score -2):

"In that" is an adverb connector which means "since" or "because". It, meanwhile, can interchangeably be used.

Comment: Your use of *it* is very confusing.